# Does restangular support synchronous request?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Per the question, does restangular have some kind of switch that could be used to turn on synchronous way for sending requests? like

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: $scope.baseURL,
            data: {
              name: $scope.name
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            **async: false,**
          })
          .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {...})
          .fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {...}
);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since the browser does not support sync call, not library can support it. They maybe able to simulate it.

Comment: Does $http support it? If it does, then Restangular can as well

Answer (score 0):

Restangular use $http from angular, and $http returns always promise

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

so every $http call is asynchronous , but anyways i dont get why you have motivation to make something "synchronous" inside angular.

Comment: I personally need it so i can send a final ajax call to the server in the unload function